# Compiling Castle.ActiveRecord to allow partial trust?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, castle, partial-trust

How can I build Castle.Core, Castle.ActiveRecord and NHibernate to allow partial trust? There are plenty of resources on the web showing how this can be done, however every site I found says to use `nant build -D:assembly.allow-partially-trusted-callers=true` to build each assembly. When I look at the Castle.Core [trunk](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Core) here there is no *.build file.

How can this be accomplished? I am using .NET 3.5 . This is not a web application.

Edit: We're using NHibernate 2.1.2GA (latest stable version, I believe). The problem with the instructions given below is that it looks like their referring to building Castle.Core and Castle.ActiveRecord from trunk. Trunk appears to be requiring NHibernate 3.0.0 which doesn't match our version.

## Solution

Almost all of my tweaks were done in the Security tab under project properties.

- Under the "Zone your application will be installed from:" label I selected "(Custom)"
- As for the permissions required by the application, I had to include SqlClientPermission as well as UIPermission. In order to negate problems for future development I selected "Grant assemblies unrestricted access to x" where is the selected permission. That was done for both permissions shown above. Note that the permissions you select to include will be on a per application basis and no two cases will be the same.
- Under the "Advanced..." button I unselected both options ("Debug this application with the selected permission set" and "Grant the application access to its site of origin").

Also, since the application and SQL Server are residing under different domains I had to set my connection string to include the database server domain. So my original connection string data source had to go from "Data Source=DB_SERVER" to "Data Source=DB_SERVER.DOMAIN".

Lastly, I had to set `requirePermission="false"` on all of my configuration sections. My `configSections` ended up like this:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="activerecord" type="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Config.ActiveRecordSectionHandler, Castle.ActiveRecord" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="nhibernate" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" requirePermission="false" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>
```

After everything was said and done I was successfully able to publish this application on a file share from a different domain and have the users install the application with no issues. Applying these steps to our other applications and using our newly compiled assemblies also worked like a charm.

Comment: try the suggestions from this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/90d8fbdcc2c363ae

Comment: @Mauricio, unfortunately that link is still causing the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need MSBuild **4.0**, the nant build scripts have since long gone.

If you've got Visual Studio 2010, open the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt otherwise make sure you use MSBuild from the .NET 4.0 framework.

Given you've got NHibernate built for APTCA (nant -D:-D:assembly.allow-partially-trusted-callers=true works thre)

- cd Core
- MSBuild buildscripts\build.proj /p:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers=true 
  /p:Configuration=NET35-Release
- Copy Castle.Core.dll from the build folder to ActiveRecord\lib\net35
- cd ActiveRecord
- MSBuild buildscripts\build.proj 
  /p:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers=true /p:Configuration=Release 
  /p:FrameworkVersion=v3.5 /p:BuildConfigKey=NET35

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What versions of Core and ActiveRecord do I need? Were using the latest stable version of AR (2.1.1). Seems the latest stable version of AR is 2.1.0 requires Core 1.2.0, which doesn't include the msbuild scripts. I'm now successfully able to build everything if I grab the trunk version of Core and AR but AR v2.1.2 requires NHibernate 3.0. Or even better is Core and AR trunk stable enough for production?

Comment: You'll need Core 1.2.0 (the 1-2-stable branch on Github) and this version is using NAnt (nant -D:assembly.allow-partially-trusted-callers=true). For ActiveRecord you need the 2-1-stable branch, which also was using NAnt instead of MSBuild.

Comment: We use trunk versions of Core and AR in production. Castle's trunk has always been very stable, at least for us.

Comment: Thank you very much! After a few hickups I managed to get everything up and running. Part of my problem was configuring my VS2008 solution to allow certain security features.

Comment: See also the castle users mailing list for how Mike managed to get things up and running: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/e123cf60537569dd?hl=en